# Momentjs get current GMT unix time

Tags: javascript, unix, momentjs

Backend API for a project I am working on only accepts the UNIX time.

The server is set in GMT so to send the UNIX time in GMT I am having to manipulate the data according to the timezone to get the results I need.

Is there a better way than below in momentJS to get the current UNIX time in GMT?

```
  var timeOffset = moment().utcOffset();

  if (timeOffset >= 0) {
    this.sinceNow = moment().subtract(timeOffset, 'minutes').unix();
  }
  else {
    this.sinceNow = moment().add(timeOffset * -1, 'minutes').unix();
  }
```

Comment: As a friendly reminder to yourself and others that may read this: Any time you find yourself manually manipulating time zone offsets, *in any language*, you are probably not using the correct API.  There are very few exceptions unless you are writing a date/time library.

Answer (score 3):

According to MomentJS documentation I believe it will be:

```
var gmt = moment().utc(), // this gives the UTC/GMT time
    unix = gmt.unix();    // this gives the Unix time
```

Comment: Yes, but `moment.utc()` is slightly more efficient, as it does the conversion on initialization.

Comment: This actually does not work. The resulting timestamp will be in localtime if you use moment in localmode.

Answer (score 0):

Please us to get GMT TimeStamp using moment.js

```
var moment = require('moment');
dt = moment();
dt.subtract(dt.parseZone().utcOffset(), 'minutes')

console.log(dt.unix());
```